# Don't Allow Access to Twitter Accounts Automatically

Tags: ios, twitter, uialertview, twitter-fabric

I am trying to get my iOS application to logout of Twitter. I have been able to create a method that clears the Twitter api cookies, reseting the current session. However, the **only** way to make the logout successful is by choosing **"Don't Allow"**, disallowing Twitter access to TWTR accounts on the device (this is prompted upon clicking the Twitter login button the first time).

My question is this:

- Is there a way to prevent the alert view from appearing upon the
  first time click by automatically choosing "Don't Allow"?

Any help
   would be apprecaited - I'm stumped! Thanks

*FYI: here is a screen shot of the prompt that appears when the user attempts a login the first time*

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of this security measure if you could circumvent it?

Comment: i guess you are right. I always thought Twitter Accounts to be any account that is saved on the device either from previous log ins or from the Twitter app itself. Either way I was just wondering if there was a way to do what my question stated